# Autocomplete isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a problem with my autocomplete. When I use the first one input text will be used for autocomplete but when I use add function that I create to append the same element like the first one it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#addCF").click(function(){
$("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom Field</label></th><td><input type="text" class="med"  name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="รายชื่อยา" />&nbsp; <input type="text" class="code" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
                });

$("#customFields").on('click', '#remCF', function(){
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
                    }       );

                    });

                    </script>

                    <script>//auto complete Code
 $(function() {
$('.med').autocomplete({
source: "show.php",minLength: 2,
select:function( event, ui ) {
 $('#name').val(ui.item.name);
}
});

});
</script>


<table class="form-table" id="customFields">
            <div id="name" ></div>
    <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom Field</label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="med"  name="customFieldName[]" value="" placeholder="รายชื่อยา" /> &nbsp;
            <input type="text" class="code" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="จำนวน" /> &nbsp;

            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addCF">ADD</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/earc4436/3/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using an ID in your Javascript, when you add the second field they are duplicated. You either need to use a class or change the ID for each field in your form.

```
<input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue" name="customFieldValue[]" 
value="" placeholder="จำนวน" />
```

Comment: i already delete every id tag but the result is the same thank you